# Pandas str.replace() with regex

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

Say I have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col': ['DDJFHGBC', 'AWDGUYABC']})
```

And I want to replace everything ending with `ABC` with `ABC` and everything ending with `BC` (except the `ABC`-cases) with `BC`. The output would look like:

```
    Col
0   BC
1   ABC
```

How can I achieve this using regular expressions? I've tried things like:

```
df.Col.str.replace(r'\w*BC\b', 'BC')
df.Col.str.replace(r'\w*ABC\b', 'ABC')
```

But obviously these two lines are conflicting and I would end up with just `BC` in whichever order I use them.

Comment: What is the goal here?

Comment: I fail to understand the purpose. Maybe add more examples so we can see the logic behind what you want.

Comment: To replace everything ending with `ABC` with `ABC` and everything ending with `BC` (except the `ABC`-cases) with `BC`.

Comment: Perhaps match `A?BC$` or match `\w*?(A?BC)\b` and replace with group 1 https://regex101.com/r/fMcfHI/1

Comment: I realize it should be sufficient to replace everything before `BC` or `ABC` with `""`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could match as least word chars using `\w*?` and then capture in group 1 matching an optional A followed by BC `(A?BC)` followed by a word boundary.

```
\w*?(A?BC)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2EaKua/1)

In there replacement use group 1

```
df.Col.str.replace(r'\w*?(A?BC)\b', r'\1')
```

Answer (score 2):

You may a `replace` solution like:

```
df['Col'].str.replace(r'(?s)^.*?(A?BC)$', r'\1')
# 0     BC
# 1    ABC
```

Here, [`(?s).*?(A?BC)$`](https://regex101.com/r/eAEypX/2) matches

- `(?s)` - a `.` will match any char including line break chars
- `^` - start of string
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `(A?BC)` - Group 1 (referred to with `\1` from the replacement pattern): an optional `A` and then `BC`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: This is not the best solution as it would alter strings that end with neither `BC` nor `ABC`.

Comment: @CHRD Which one? I have just finished writing the answer. BTW, both "work" for your data, in your question, there is no indication what to do with no-matches.

Comment: I meant the first one. Thank you!

Comment: @CHRD What if you have `1ABC 2ABC`? What will be the expected result?

Comment: They would still end up as `ABC`.

Comment: @CHRD I mean if you have `pd.DataFrame({'Col': ['1ABC 2ABC']})`? Do you expect `ABC`as a result?

Comment: Then I'd want the output to get rid of the digits.

Comment: @CHRD Good, I think you should add that point to the question.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
df.Col.str.replace(r'\w*ABC\b', 'ABC_').str.replace(r'\w*BC\b', 'BC').str.replace(r'\w*ABC_\b', 'ABC')
```

It first replaces `\w*ABC\b` with `ABC_`. `ABC_` won't be affected by `replace(r'\w*BC\b', 'BC')`.

Then it replaces `ABC_` with `ABC` to convert the string back to the original one.

Comment: This works. But how about replacing everything before `BC` or `ABC` with `""`? That would only require one `.replace()`.